# T-SQL Pattern matching

Tags: sql, t-sql, pattern-matching, sql-like

I am trying to find a way to query rows of data by using a "multivalue" pipe delimited column in another table as a WHERE clause.  SQL SERVER 2005

This is my best description of the problem:

Imagine a pipe delimited column set to a variable like  @LIST  = 'Bob|Mary|Joe'

then I am trying to find a match like this

```
Select * from Users where FirstName = 'Joe'
```

but extended to be

```
Select * from Users where FirstName "IS CONTAINED IN" @List
```

which would return all the Bob, Mary and Joe entries.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Good luck. SQL is meant for querying normalized data, not pipe-delimited strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a split udf and join it to your main query. see this [link](http://www.sqlmag.com/Article/ArticleID/21071/sql_server_21071.html) for the code and an example. Your query would end up looking like this. This is untested but hopefully this points you in the right direction.

```
Select A.* from Users A JOIN dbo.Fn_Split(@ValueArrayString, '|') B on A.FirstName = B.value
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
Select * from Users where CHARINDEX(FirstName + '|', @List + '|') > 0
```

A little annoying that you have to append the pipe delimiter to both strings, but it works, and it's probably faster than a function.

Comment: This is pretty neat. +1! (However , I'm wondering why it cannot be just charindex(FirstName,@List) ?

Comment: That could give false matches, ie if a name in the list was BillyBob, it'd match incorrectly without the additional delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

I like MrTelly's solution. However, it's only taking care of half the false-positives.
The full solution is as follows:

```
Select * from Users where CHARINDEX('|' + FirstName + '|', '|' + @List + '|') > 0
```

The pipe needs to be added on both ends

Answer (score 0):

Check out the PATINDEX() function. It's a bit limited, but it should do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[See udf___Txt_SplitTab](http://www.novicksoftware.com/UDFofWeek/Vol1/T-SQL-UDF-Volume-1-Number-29-udf_Txt_SplitTAB.htm) from Andrew Novick

```
Select * from Users where FirstName IN (Select Item From udf_Txt_SplitTAB (@LIST, '|'))
```